# Dynamically invoke a class method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Suppose I have Objective C interface `SomeClass` which has a class method called `someMethod`:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
}

+ (id)someMethod;
@end
```

In some other interface I want to have a helper method that would dynamically invoke `someMethod` on a class like this:

```
[someOtherObject invokeSelector:@selector(someMethod) forClass:[SomeClass class];
```

What should be the implementation for `invokeSelector`? Is it possible at all?

```
- (void)invokeSelector:(SEL)aSelector forClass:(Class)aClass {
   // ???
}
```

Comment: In your example code you are declaring SomeClass as a root class. There should incredibly rarely be a need for this. Is it just a mistake in your question?

Comment: Yes. It is a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[someOtherObject invokeSelector:@selector(someMethod) forClass:[SomeClass class];
```

call:

```
[[SomeClass class] performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
```

Example (using GNUstep ...)

file A.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface A : NSObject {}

- (NSString *)description;
+ (NSString *)action;
@end
```

file A.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "A.h"

@implementation A

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithString: @"A"];
}

+ (NSString *)action
{
    return [NSString stringWithString:@"A::action"];
}

@end
```

Somewhere else:

```
A *a = [[A class] performSelector:@selector(action)];
NSLog(@"%@",a);
```

Output:

```
2009-11-22 23:32:41.974 abc[3200] A::action
```

---

nice explanation from http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/197631-how-do-classes-respond-to-performselector.html:

"In Objective-C, a class object gets all the instance methods of the
root class for its hierarchy.  This means that every class object
that descends from NSObject gets all of NSObject's instance methods -
including performSelector:."

Comment: I knew I could use performSelector on NSObject. However, I was confused because I thought the type Class didn't have performSelector method. I didn't bother to try.

Comment: Code Sense doesn't suggest `performSelector` for `[SomeClass class]` experssion.

Comment: I'm not in front of my Mac, so I tried on Linux with GNUStep and it works ... :)

Comment: His class doesn't implement NSObject.

Comment: True, but it's a simple fix to get the `performSelector` functionality

Comment: you can just do `[A performSelector:@selector(action)];`

Comment: There's also the `performSelector:withObject:` selector, similarly not suggested by Code Sense.

Answer (score 4):

In Objective-C, classes are objects as well. The class objects are treated differently, however, as they can call the instance methods of their root class (`NSObject` or `NSProxy` in Cocoa).

So it's possible to use all the instance methods defined in `NSObject` on class objects as well and the right way to dynamically invoke a class method is:

```
[aClass performSelector:@selector(aSelector)];
```

The [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW52) are a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't implement this yourself.

The NSObject Protocol has a [`performSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:) method that does exactly this.

Comment: Type Class is not NSObject. It doesn't have performSelector method

Comment: Do `Class` objects implement the `NSObject` protocol?

Comment: How are you creating an object that isn't an NSObject? From the top of the page of the link I give: "The NSObject protocol groups methods that are fundamental to all Objective-C objects."

Comment: @Ben S: He's trying to invoke a class method. `Class` objects don't descend from `NSObject`.

Comment: @mipadi: You're absolutely right. Do you know why it works nevertheless?

Comment: No. The Objective-C `Object` (defined in `/usr/include/objc/Object.h`) defines a perform: method with the same signature. A `Class` object might descend from `Object`, but even that wouldn't explain it; and I haven't found anything in the Foundation framework that monkeypatches `Class` to respond to `performSelector:`.

Comment: In Objective-C classes are objects, direct subclasses of NSObject. Every instance method defined on NSObject will work on a class.

Comment: @Mike: Yes, but a `Class` *object* doesn't descend from `NSObject`.

Comment: @mipadi: `Class` is not a class, but a generic type for pointers to class objects. Each class object is an instance of its meta-class, which follows an inheritance chain that ultimately ends in the root class of the class in question, which is in this case `NSObject`. So yet, it descends from NSObject.

Comment: How would you pass parameters? Any way to get auto-complete in Xcode when typing the selector name?

Answer (score 2):

Is this built-in method what you want?

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

(See the [runtime reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime?language=objc) for this function.)

Comment: From your link: "This reference is useful primarily for developing bridge layers between Objective-C and other languages, or for low-level debugging. You typically do not need to use the Objective-C runtime library directly when programming in Objective-C."

Comment: But isn't avoiding built-in checks and balances the whole point of dynamically sending messages?

Comment: Never mind; didn't notice that it wasn't a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: I think this is the best option then.