# Can I use a class method as a delegate callback

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In a class method method I declare the following:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello" 
                                                   message:@"World"
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
```

Now even though the containing method is a class method, the compiler does not complain about the `delegate:self`. Now to be the delegate I have to implement the method in `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

Does it now matter, if the method is a class method or not, in order to be called when the user interacts with my AlertView?

I am asking this question, because my class does not have any instance variables so I would prefer it to contain class methods only.

Comment: You could try the class name instead of self, which refers to the instance.

Comment: Also see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781046/dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-objective-c. It's relevan I think.

Comment: in a class method self refers to the class, and not to an object of the class. does this code run?

Comment: I edited `static method` and changed it to `class method` thanks for the remark. I guess that's my Java background haunting me :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I assume by "static" methods, you mean class methods (declared with `+` instead of `-`).

"The compiler does not complain" about Objective-C doesn't always tell you much. All it really means is that you have convinced the compiler that everything should (or at least *could*) work at runtime.

In the end, if the object you provide as a delegate responds to the right messages, the compiler won't care that it's a class (and neither will the runtime). In this case, you are providing `self` from a class method. It is as though you typed `[MyClass class]`.

I think it's probably questionable whether this is what you *should* do--but that's probably outside the bounds of your question.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to share some of my findings:

1. It does not matter whether I declare the delegate like this `delegate:self` or `delegate:[MyClass class]`
2. However, it does matter how I declare the method:

   **This works**

   ```
   +(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
       // Some Actions here
   }
   ```

   Although the following "syntax" is the declaration in the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol, it **does not work**:

   ```
   // Mind the `-` sign at the start of the line.
   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
       // Some Actions here
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, `self` and `[MyClass class]` are equivalent within a "MyClass" method.

If you want your class itself to be the delegate, then you have to declare this as a class method. The documentation is describing how to implement the instance method, which I think is pretty much universally "how it's done". In the end what really matters is that whatever object you provide as the delegate responds to the "alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:" selector.

So, yes, the answer is still that you *can* do it. Whether you should is different.

Comment: Wow!  Not in a million years would I have guess that turning the delegate method into a class method would be the way to go.  Thank you, thank you!  I have lost 5+ hours trying to solve a similar problem.  ... didn't need NSCondition or performSelector or anything!

Comment: I'm using a class method as my `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`, and I get this warning: `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> _Nullable' from 'Class _Nullable'`
My @interface has `<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>`, but how do I do that for a class method and avoid the warning?

Comment: @Jeff. My answer is 8 years old so I'm a bit out of practise. I suggest you open a new question and maybe reference this post in it. I'm sorry to not being able to offer you a better answer.

Comment: @Besi.  Thank you.  I've found a reasonable workaround (it gets rid of the warning).  I add `(id)` thusly, `controller.mailComposeDelegate = (id)[self class];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can !!! A class is also an object.