# UIColor resolveClassMethod not resolving from selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I'm having issues with this code :

```
NSString *value = (NSString*)[self.colorsData objectForKey:key]; 
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(value);   
BOOL isColorMethod = [[UIColor class] resolveClassMethod:selector];
```

The String value being passed in as the `SEL` selector is `@"redColor"`, which as you know is a class method of `UIColor`; but the `'isColorMethod'` `BOOL` always returns NO.

This code is for a Styling engine I am building.

Comment: Frankly, I do not have the answer to your question. But why don't you just putt UIColor objects into your colorsData array? They hardly consume much more memory than an NSString object.

Comment: because my color values are being pulled in from plist as Strings. I am converting strings as hex, RGB and friendly names like 'red', 'blue' etc. I'm building a theme engine.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `[UIColor resolveClassMethod:selector];` ? Maybe it does not make much of a difference anyway.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to achieve by calling `resolveClassMethod`in this context? Are you gong to add a custom `redColur` to UIColor? Or are you just trying to call the factory methods dynamically? If yes than have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781046/dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-objective-c

Comment: Ah, I guess that you want to check whether the value in `value` actually corresponds to a proper class method name.

Comment: Why vote this question down? It is perfectly valid, and, yes, I did look to see if it had been asked elsewhere.

Comment: The code in this question relates to this gist : https://gist.github.com/leeprobert/5442137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong method. If you want to know whether something is a string method you should use [`respondsToSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a) and [`instancesRespondToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/instancesRespondToSelector%3a).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a fix ... you can do this instead, despite `respondsToSelector` not showing as an available class method :

```
BOOL isColorMethod = [[UIColor class] respondsToSelector:selector];
```

I'm not sure why `resolveClassMethod` doesn't work when `respondsToSelector` does, however.

So, although I am answering my own question I would be interested in knowing what is happening here.