# iOS Objective-C - Call Class Method On Class Dynamically Created With NSClassFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that I can call a class method like `[MyClass myMethod];` by doing `[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];`

I'm currently trying to do this however:

```
[MyClass configureWithNum:@"12345"
       andNumber:@"2312312"
       options:nil
       completion:^(NSArray<SecondClass*>* array) {}
     ];
```

When I do this:

```
[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") performSelector:@selector(configureWithNum)
            withObject:@"12345"
            withObject:@"2312312"
            withObject:nil
            withObject:^(NSArray<SecondClass*>* array) {}];
```

It throws an `Undeclared selection 'configureWithNum'`.

It seems like the performSelector withObject call only works for one parameter. So I suspect I need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781046/dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-objective-c#answer-1781054) using `objc_msgSend` but I can't seem to get the format right.

I think [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments) is along the right track - but I can't seem to get it right. When I do this:

```
objc_msgSend(NSClassFromString(@"MyClass"), sel_getUid("configureWithNum:andNumber:options:completion:"), @"12345", @"2312312", nil, ^(NSArray<AdColonyZone*>* zones) {});
```

It gives me a `implicit declaration of function 'objc_msgSend' is invalid in C99` error.

Any ideas how to implement this call using either the `objc_msgSend` or `performSelector: withObject:`?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no method with multiple `withObject`. You should encapsulate all your data in single object such as NSArray or NSDictionary and then pass it as a argument.

For examples:

```
NSArray * arrayParams = 
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"firstParams", @"secondParams", nil];

[self performSelector:@selector(configureWithNum:) 
           withObject:arrayParams];
```

Comment: So for this one, I don't need to explicitly call out the param names, I can just pass the params more or less?

Answer (score 0):

`Implicit declaration of function 'objc_msgSend' is invalid in C99` error means, that you didn't include required header.

```
#include <objc/message.h>
```

should fix this problem.